# How to have variables combined into one variable when file scanner has scanned more than 1 true statment

Tags: java

Im creating a simple Java program but I ran into something I haven't thought of. Long story short, im creating a word file on my desktop, each line has a number followed by a letter. Letters that are alike have the same starting number. So I implemented some code with a few tweaks i found on the interent. The code is basically "if the line starts with 001, the letter/word next to 001 is going to be the variable 001Letters ".Im using the java.util.Scanner and my starting code is:

```
 while (scanner.hasNext()) {
    String lineOfText = scanner.nextLine();

    if (lineOfText.startsWith("001")) {
          lineOfText = lineOfText.substring(3);
       System.out.println(lineOfText);
       001Letters.setText(lineOfText);
       ******//001Letters is the JLabel that is suppose // to show all letters within the 001 group******
    }
 }
```

A-Okay. So my thinking was that all the letters that had a 001 infront of it were going to be combined. But instead it just gives me the latest line that starts with 001 and its letter. How can I make it to where if I have 2+ lines that start with 001, both letter are combined so I can make one variable. An example:

**001 A**

002 X

003 B

**001 M**

**001 N**

005 L

So that when its calculated and pasted on my GUI window, it'll show "A M N".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside the loop append each value to a string variable and after the loop is finished set this string value to `Letters001`:

```
    String line = "";
    while (scanner.hasNext()) {
        String lineOfText = scanner.nextLine();
        if (lineOfText.startsWith("001")) {
            lineOfText = lineOfText.substring(3);
            System.out.println(lineOfText);
            line += lineOfText + "<br>";
        }
    }
    if (line.length() > 0) {
        line = "<html>" + line.substring(0, line.length() - 4) + "</html>";
    }
    Letters001.setText(line);
```

Comment: So you want a line break instead of a space between the letters?

Comment: Thanks, work perfectly. Do you know of anyway on how to add a line break in between the letters? I thought that inserting the "<HTML>" + "<br/>" + "</HTML>" would insert a line break, with "<br>" after the......" "; but I guess it doesn't work. Any way on how to achieve this?

Comment: Change to: `line += lineOfText + "\n";`

Comment: if I add "/n" it just shows up as any regular string i.e (A/nB/nC/nD

Comment: Not /n but `\n`.

Comment: Still doesn't work. Just want to make sure you know its a JLabel because I know \n works with console. On the JLabel it just looks like any another space

Comment: For a JLabel you need Html. Give me a few mins.

Comment: Thanks for the effort man but I just get "A</html>N</html>M" and so on.

Comment: Thanks so much, finally got it. Althought when I copied and pasted it there seemed to be a problem with the brackets. All my brackets were upshifted so after a few minutes of randomly putting brackets in places I finally got it working. Thank you!